# 'gem install [name of gem] --pre' is not updating my system gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am a newbie when it comes to working with gems so pardon me if i'm getting my facts wrong.

I want to update Bundler from v1.3.5 to the latest version (v1.5.3) so I tried doing:

```
sudo gem install bundler --pre
```

the command line outputs:

```
Fetching: bundler-1.5.3.gem (100%)Fetching: bundler-1.5.3.gem
Successfully installed bundler-1.5.3
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.5.3
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.5.3
Done installing documentation for bundler after 4 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but when I do `gem list` or `bundle --version`, it shows that i'm still using the old version (v1.3.5). This goes to all my other gems. I tried updating Susy, Sass and Compass the same way, but it doesn't get updated even though it says that it was installed successfully.

Any ideas? TIA

Comment: Are you using a ruby version manager like rvm or rbenv at all?

Comment: @mralexlau i'm using RVM.

Comment: Try doing `rvm list` before you run your `gem install bundler` command and again before `gem list`. Make sure you're on the same version of ruby between each command.

Comment: @mralexlau sorry, that didn't do anything different

Comment: I would probably just do `gem uninstall bundler` then `gem install bundler --pre` in that case. If you truly have multiple versions of a gem installed, `gem uninstall` will prompt you for which one you want to uninstall.

Comment: @mralexlau uninstall bundler made me choose what version I want to install. I uninstalled all but after doing so, it seems that gem list still has the bundler gem (v1.3.5) and bundle --version still works. And also, v1.3.5 didn't appear in the choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. It seems that if you add `sudo` when installing gems, it installs the gem on a different directory from the one used when you don't use `sudo`. I saw this when I did `sudo gem list` and it displayed different results from a normal `gem list` command.

To be able to add gems without `sudo` I just did `chown -R [current_user] [ruby_directory]`

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle update` on the command line. This will update your gems in your app.